# Determinant properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Prove without expanding:
\begin{equation}\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\a^2&b^2&c^2\\a^3&b^3 & c^3\end{vmatrix} = (ab + ac + bc)(b - a)(c - a)(c - b)\end{equation}

---

I tried to zero some elements and expand until I reach the Right hand side.

Also tried C1-C3, C2-C3 then decompose the determinant into two determinants and taking common factors. But I couldn't get (ab + ac + bc) part.

I can only use the properties shown here http://www.vitutor.com/alg/determinants/properties_determinants.html

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like cofactor expansion across the top row would be a good idea.

Comment: The minor associatedd to the upper left hand entry is $b^{2}c^{3}-c^{2}b^{3}$. Include the other two minors, expand and factorise.

Comment: You're *telling* us what *we* should do?

Comment: @GFauxPas Aww, there's no need to be like that.

Comment: Still unclear.  The recent Edit adjures Readers to prove "without expanding by using determinant properties".  However the purpose of doing A without B is not explained, nor is it clear what remains allowed if using determinant properties is forbidden.

Comment: It would be better to include those determinant properties in your question. But the improvement by your edit is good enough for me to vote to reopen the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a long proof but that's the only way I could answer it.
\begin{gather*}
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\a^2&b^2&c^2\\a^3&b^3&c^3\end{bmatrix} \\
= \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\a^2&b^2-a^2&c^2-a^2\\a^3&b^3-a^3&c^3 - a^3\end{bmatrix} \\
= (b-a)(c-a)\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\a^2&b+a&c+a\\a^3&b^2+ab+a^2&c^2+ac+a^2\end{bmatrix} \\
= (b-a)(c-a)\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\a^2&b+a&c-b\\a^3&b^2+ab+a^2&c^2-b^2+ac-ab\end{bmatrix} \\
= (b-a)(c-a)(c-b)\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\a^2&b+a&1\\a^3&b^2+ab+a^2&a+b+c\end{bmatrix}\\
= (b-a)(c-a)(c-b)[(b+a)(a+b+c)-(b^2+ab+a^2)] \\
= (ab+ac+bc)(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)\\
= R.H.S
\end{gather*}

Answer (score 2):

First note that the determinant is cyclic. Hence, it is of the form $f(a,b,c)$, where $f$ is a polynomial of degree $5$. Further, we have
$f(a,a,c) = f(a,b,b) = f(c,b,c) = 0$, which means $(a-b)$, $(b-c)$ and $(c-a)$ are factors, i.e., the determinant is $g(a,b,c)(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$, where $g(a,b,c)$ is a cyclic polynomial of degree $2$. Any cyclic polynomial of degree $2$ is of the form $x(a^2+b^2+c^2)+y(ab+bc+ca)$. Setting $a=0$, we see that the determinant is $b^2c^3-b^3c^2 = b^2c^2(c-b)$. We also have
$$f(0,b,c) = g(0,b,c)(-b)(b-c)c = \left(x(b^2+c^2)+ybc \right)bc(c-b)$$
This means we need
$$\left(x(b^2+c^2)+ybc \right)bc(c-b) = b^2c^2(c-b) \implies x(b^2+c^2)+ybc = bc \implies x=0,y=1$$
Hence, we obtain that the determinant is
$$(ab+bc+ca)(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{gather*}
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\a^2&b^2&c^2\\a^3&b^3&c^3\end{bmatrix} \\
= \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\a^2&b^2-a^2&c^2-a^2\\a^3&b^3-a^3&c^3 - a^3\end{bmatrix} \\
= \begin{bmatrix}b^2-a^2&c^2-a^2\\b^3-a^3&c^3 - a^3\end{bmatrix} \\
= (b^2-a^2)(c^3 - a^3)-(b^3-a^3)(c^2 - a^2)
= (b-a)(c-a)[(b+a)(c^2+ac+a^2)-(c+a)(b^2+ab+a^2)] \\
= (ab+ac+bc)(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)\\
= R.H.S
\end{gather*}