# Need help with matrix problems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

1) Verify the equation
$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        a & b & c \\
        a^3 &b^3 & c^3 \\
        \end{vmatrix}== (a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(a+b+c)
$$

2) Show that the points (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3) are collinear if

$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
        x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
        x_3 &y_3 & 1 \\
        \end{vmatrix}=0
$$

For the first problem I get
$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & b-a & c -a\\
        0 &0 & (a^2+ab+b^2)(c-a) - (c^3-a^3) \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$

to

$(b-a)(c-a)[a^2 + ab + b^2 - (c^2 - a^2)]$
No idea on how to get the $(a-b)(a+b+c)$

The second problem I have no idea what to do, I'm stuck with

$x_1(y_2-y_3) - y_1(x_2-x_3) + (x_2y_3 - x_3y_2)$

I have heard of something where I must divide numbers and find identical slopes but with no given points I'm practically clueless in this question

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735883/calculate-determinant-of-vandermonde-using-specified-steps?lq=1

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273025/determinant-properties

Comment: Do not ask two questions in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation to
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & b-a & c -a\\
        0 &0 & (a^2+ab+b^2)(c-a) - (c^3-a^3) \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$
is almost correct, but you must have swapped some row somewhere without changing the sign. Now this one has the determinant
$$
(b-a)((a^2+ab+b^2)(c-a) - (c^3-a^3) = (b-a)(c-a)(a^2+ab+b^2-(c^2+ac+a^2))
$$
which simplifies to 
$$
(a-b)(a-c)(ab+b^2-ac-c^2) = (a-b)(a-c)(b-c)(a+b+c) \, .
$$
So your last steps must have some algebraic errors.

For the second problem, collinearity means that there are numbers $a,b,c$, not all zero, such that $ax_i + by_i + c = 0$ for $i = 1,2,3$ (all three points satisfy the same line equation). That is, three separate equations are satisfied by $a,b,c$.  Now write these three equations as a matrix vector equation. Then this says that a certain matrix is singular (has a nontrivial null vector) and therefore its determinant is zero. You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and help! :)